# Python Fabric - No hosts found. Please specify (single) host string for connection:

Tags: python, fabric

How do I get No hosts found. Please specify (single) host string for connection: ?

How to a resolve with fabric?

```
def bootstrap():
    host = 'ec2-54-xxx.xxx.xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com'
    env.hosts = [host]
    env.user = "ubuntu"
    env.key_filename = "/home/ubuntu/omg.pem"

> command run
>> fab bootstrap
> No hosts found. Please specify (single) host string for connection:
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Instead of setting hosts inside your task, do it before it gets called with a decorator:

```
from fabric.api import hosts, env

@hosts(['ec2-54-xxx.xxx.xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com'])
def bootstrap():
    env.user = "ubuntu"
    env.key_filename = "/home/ubuntu/omg.pem"
```

For more information on this, check out [Defining host lists](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.4.0/usage/execution.html#defining-host-lists) - there are a lot of different ways to do it depending on what you need.

Comment: Thanks for this solution. I was having an issue where i need to define different type of hosts to a different function. With this solution i was able to fix my problem.

Comment: The page do not exist.

Answer (score 25):

Also you can use env.host_string instead of env.hosts:

```
def bootstrap():
    env.host_string # 'ec2-54-xxx.xxx.xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com'
    env.user = "ubuntu"
    env.key_filename = "/home/ubuntu/omg.pem"
```

Comment: Thanks!, I also needed `env.disable_known_hosts = True`

Answer (score 3):

Alternatevly you can set env settings in outside your functions

```
from fabric.api import env, run

host = 'ec2-54-xxx.xxx.xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com'
env.hosts = [host]
env.user = "ubuntu"
env.key_filename = "/home/ubuntu/omg.pem"

def test():
    run('ls -la')
```