# How to push command by python fabric to multiple hosts?

Tags: python, fabric

I don't uderstand how to define multiple hosts in python fabric. I have a `hosts.txt` file contains a connection data in this form:

```
user@hostname:22 password
user@otherhost:22 password
user@thirdhost:22 password
```

and sample code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import pprint
from fabric.api import *

for line in open('hosts.txt','r').readlines():
    host, passw = line.split()
    env.hosts.append(host)
    env.passwords[host] = passw

pprint.pprint( env.hosts )

def test():
 sudo("mkdir /a")

test();
```

Unfortunately I'm getting message

> No hosts found. Please specify (single) host string for connection

`pprint` shows me a proper hosts list. What should I do to perform my tasks to all hosts inside `hosts.txt` file?

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/a/15621751/489590

Answer (score 0):

I doing it wrong way. Instead of calling a function from a python file, i should run it from command line this way:

```
fab -f my_file_with_functions function_name
```

so this solves the problem